# Votes can have different value

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I find an answer which is so incredibly helpful or beautiful that I would not mind voting double, triple or more at the cost of reputation, sort of like a bounty for existing answers. - Does anyone recognize this?

Answer (score 22):

> sort of like a bounty for existing answers

But ... that's exactly one of the dedicated purposes for bounties:

[image]

An additional benefit is that a bounty bumps the question to the homepage, and it gets [featured](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties), so you might inspire more users to vote for the answer.

Comment: OK. Got that. I thought bounties were only meant for new questions! Thanks